# background image display on different devices

Tags: css

[image]I have only one image which is https://dummyimage.com/fullbanner. Below are the requirement.

https://jsfiddle.net/moorthy/ygn0Ldbw/1/

1) I would like to repeat the background image in footer for 100% width.

2) I would like to display the image without cut/crop for different devices based on browser width and device width.

I have tried with below code and different media queries with different pixels to achieve this but i could not get desired result. For some pixels and during resize of browser, some part of images getting cropped.

I tried with media queries 320,480,600,768,900,1024,1200 .. px but background image is not covered properly for all px.

Is it possible to display same image properly in different devices? I tried with background-size with different values like cover and contain but it didnt work properly.

for.e.g

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myPattern"></div>
</div>

#container{
    width:100%;
    height:71px;
    background-color:black;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position : fixed;
}

#myPattern
{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/fullbanner");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `background-size: contain;` instead of `auto`

Comment: tried with contain but it didnt work for my requirement. I have attached the image which is getting cropped. i wanted something like if less than 480px, it should display only one image in footer. if between 481 to 768px, 2 times image should be repeated and displayed with auto aligned. if 768 to 1200px, 3 times image should be repeated and displayed. if more than 1200px, 4 times image should be repeated and displayed. I m looking for auto alignment of image based on width of browser/devices width.